# Use spark to convert file compression format

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I need to change a bunch of files' compression formats, and output them with the same subdirectory names and file names. For example, if the input is like:

```
/user/me/project/2017-3-06/ {part-r-00001.lzo, part-r-00002.lzo, ...}
/user/me/project/2017-3-07/ {part-r-00001.lzo, part-r-00002.lzo, ...}
/user/me/project/2017-3-08/ {part-r-00001.lzo, part-r-00002.lzo, ...}
```

Expected output should be:

```
/user/me/project_v2/2017-3-06/ {part-r-00001.lz4, part-r-00002.lz4, ...}
/user/me/project_v2/2017-3-07/ {part-r-00001.lz4, part-r-00002.lz4, ...}
/user/me/project_v2/2017-3-08/ {part-r-00001.lz4, part-r-00002.lz4, ...}
```

Should I even use Spark to achieve that?

Comment: Can? Sure... With a little bit of creativity you can do a lot. Does it makes sense? Not at all. You'll have to do a lot of hacking against Spark without real benefits.

Comment: Suppose to ask with "Should I" instead "Can I".. Yea, as I thought, probably Spark is not the best choice for this specific task. By the way, any suggested tools to achieve that?

Comment: :) Personally I would take a look at [Luigi](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or similar batching / workflow management system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is on hdfs:
If your file is splittable, Spark is a good option to decrypt the file.

but you can't update the files directly(like gunzip) to the same location so write your output to a new location and then after deleting the original file, move new files to the original location.

ensure to use -skipTrash while deleting the files for better time efficiency.

Comment: Right, that's what we want to do. The challenge, however, is how to preserve the same file name and similar file path.

Comment: try using sc.wholeTextFiles -- this will give file absolute path as key and value as file content. Limitation to this will be file should be small.

Comment: `wholeTextFiles` is very close to what I need. But our files rollover every 1.2 GB, which can be too big to fit the purpose of `wholeTextFiles`.